# #define with if-else logic in C

Tags: c, if-statement, constants, c-preprocessor

I am simulating a client/server interaction according to [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#clientserver). At the beginning of my `server.c` file I am defining a port number with:

```
#define PORT "21124"
```

However, I will be creating several servers from this file and I would like to change this constant based on some if-else logic. Is there a functionality in C to easily accomplish this such as:

```
if (serverNumber == 1) {
  #define PORT "21124"
}
else if (serverNumber == 2) {
  #define PORT "12412"
}
else {
  #define PORT "12334"
}
```

This may be a duplicate, but I didn't see it in the search. I'm a `C` noob.

Comment: It doesn't sound like this thing is a constant. You probably shouldn't be `#define`-ing it.

Comment: You either want `#if` (not `if`) or you don't want `#define`. Probably the latter.

Comment: I understand that the question may not be applying the best practice, however, I don't see why it is being downvoted. If anything, it can be used to inform people in the future who may be inclined to make the same mistake. Anyways, I completely agree with the points everyone is making. Thank you all.

Comment: @BrianVanover maybe it is for not performing a thorough search before asking. However, since you are a noob in C, I will upvote you, but next time, try harder. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `#define` in this manner. There is if-else logic with the preprocessor using `#if`, `#elif`, and `#else`, but you must realize this is essentially hard-coding the application.

You could do this, but I don't recommend it either. Just use variables or `const` instead as there is better type safety - no need for the preprocessor:

```
#define PORT_1   "21124"
#define PORT_2   "12412"
#define PORT_3   "12334"

if (serverNumber == 1) {
    port = PORT_1;
}
else if (serverNumber == 2) {
    port = PORT_2;
}
else {
    port = PORT_3;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

"I would like to change this constant". That doesn't sound right, does it?

So, just use a variable like `int port` and assign its value with a simple if-else block of statements, or with a switch.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what are trying.

`#define` statements are processed at compile time. It doesn't make sense to use different `#define` statements based on the value of a variable at run time.

The best you can do is:

```
#define PORT_1 "21124"
#define PORT_2 "12412"
#define PORT_3 "12334"
```

Use a variable `PORT` and set its value appropriately.

```
if (serverNumber == 1) {
  PORT = PORT_1;
}
else if (serverNumber == 2) {
  PORT = PORT_2;
}
else {
  PORT = PORT_3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `#define` statements are instruction to the C preprocessor. So defining them within an `if` statement won't work. What you could do is something like this:

```
#define ServerNumber 1
#if ServerNumber == 1
#define PORT 1234
#elif ServerNumber == 2
#define PORT 1235
#endif
```

Alternatively, skip using the `#define` all together and specify this port number as a command line option.